# DNS.GetHostEntry not working after updating .net framework version

Tags: c#, .net, system.net

I am connecting to FTP and uploading files , when creating endpoint I am using dns.getHostentry method. This is working fine in .net framework 3.5 but when updated the version to 4 or later it is not working properly. For some of the sites it is throwing exception as : No such host is known. But same thing work fine when framework version is 3.5. I searched on net and found solution to use dns.resolve but those methods are deprecated. So please let me know what is the best alternative method for this.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Problem with System.Net.Dns.GetHostEntry(dnsServer) on .NET 4.0](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2714449/problem-with-system-net-dns-gethostentrydnsserver-on-net-4-0)

Comment: @ Alexander - All links are broken in above link.

Comment: Don't see on the links. The answer is "If you have input strings that you just want to convert to `IPAddresses`, it is recommended that you use `IPAddress.TryParse` or `Dns.GetHostAddresses`".